# URL Validation in Javascript InstaGram Validation

Tags: php, javascript, validation

I somehow managed to make this url validation code and it worked. But there is a problem that i'm facing. I think stackoverflow is the best place to get a solution.

```
function url_followers(){
var url=document.getElementById('ffname').value;
function validate_url(url){
var p= /^\s*(http\:\/\/)?instagram\.com\/[a-z\A-Z\d\-]{1,255}\s*$/;
if(url.match(p)){
return 1;
}else{
return 0;
}
     }
```

onsubmit it show show error if there is a wrong link entered in the text box.
Possibilities:

1. h***://instagram.com/small-letters (Alphabets with small letters)
2. h***://instagram.com/capital-letters (Alphabets with capital
   letters)
3. h***://instagram.com/username_username_username (Link may
       contain _{underscores})

The current codes only validates small and capital letters.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks :D

Comment: change [a-z\A-Z\d\-] to [a-z\A-Z\d\-_]

Comment: OmG :D This was really easy :D I dont know why i dint make ir myself :D Thanks for the help bud :D I'm actually learning to code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
/^\s*(http\:\/\/)?instagram\.com\/[a-z\d-_]{1,255}\s*$/i
```

(this will make the whole expression case insensitive in case someone enters INSTAGRAM.com)

Comment: https://www.instagram.com/tv/CXqFBP5jOkV/?utm_source=ig_web_copy_link

its a instagram copied post
but this regex not working on it !